# dynamic_cast with template class "invalid target type for dynamic_cast"

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

In a template class I'm trying to cast from a string read from a file using dynamic_cast, and want to be able to catch failed casts using the bad_cast exception. However, when compiling (with the test program setting double as the template class, I get this error for dynamic_cast:

```
datafilereader.cpp(20): error C2680: 'double *' : invalid target type for dynamic_cast
```

I've tried writing it as just `<T>` instead of `<T*>` (the latter seemed to be the common way when I looked at other questions about dynamic cast...), but practically same error.

DataFileReader.cpp

```
#include "DataFileReader.h"
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
void DataFileReader<T>::openFiles() {
    dataFileStream.open(dataFileName);
    errorFileStream.open(errorFileName, ios::app);
    if (!(dataFileStream.is_open() && errorFileStream.is_open()))
            throw(runtime_error("Couldn't open at least one of the files."));
}

template <typename T>
bool DataFileReader<T>::readNextValue(T &aValue) {
    ios_base::iostate mask = ios::eofbit|ios::failbit|ios::badbit;
    dataFileStream.exceptions(mask);
    while (true) {
        string readValue;
        try {
            dataFileStream >> readValue;
            aValue = dynamic_cast<T*>(readValue);
            return true;
        }
        catch(bad_cast &bc) {
            errorFileStream << readValue << " - " << bc.what() << endl;
        }
        catch(ios_base::failure &eo) {
            if(dataFileStream.eof())
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

DataFileReader.h

```
#ifndef DataFileReader_H
#define DataFileReader_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class DataFileReader {

    private:
        string dataFileName;
        string errorFileName;
        ifstream& dataFileStream;
        ofstream& errorFileStream;

    public: 
        DataFileReader(string aDataFileName, string aErrorFileName): dataFileName(aDataFileName), errorFileName(aErrorFileName), dataFileStream(*(new std::ifstream(""))), errorFileStream(*(new std::ofstream(""))) {};
        /* pre: A file named aDataFile contains values to read. */
        ~DataFileReader() {dataFileStream.close(); errorFileStream.close(); delete dataFileStream; delete errorFileStream;}
        /* post: Files are closed */
        void openFiles(); // throw (runtime_error);
        /* post: An input stream from the file named aDataFile and an output stream to the file named aErrorFile are opened. 
        If either of these operations fails a runtime_error exception is thrown. */
        bool readNextValue(T &aValue);
        /* pre: openFiles has been successfully called. 
        post: If a value has been successfully read, aValue holds that value and true is returned. 
        Else, the read operation encountered an end-of-file and false is returned. */
};

#endif
```

DataTestClass.cpp

```
#ifndef DataTestClass_H
#define DataTestClass_H

#include "DataFilter.cpp"
#include "DataFileReader.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <vector>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

vector<double> vec;
int rangeErrorCounter = 0;

void printResults() {
    double summa(0), medel(0);
    vector<double>::iterator first, last, it;
    first = vec.begin();
    last = vec.end();
    for (it = first; it != last; ++it)
        summa += *it;
    medel = summa/vec.size();

    cout << "Lästa numeriska värden:\t" << vec.size()+rangeErrorCounter << endl;
    cout << "Värden utanför intervallet:\t" << rangeErrorCounter << endl;
    cout << "Summa:\t\t\t" << summa << endl;
    cout << "Medelvärde:\t\t" << medel << endl;
}

int main(int args[])
{
    DataFileReader<double> dr("Values.dat", "ReadErrors.dat");

    try {
        dr.openFiles();
    }
    catch (runtime_error &rt) {
        cout << "Error reading files: " << rt.what() << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    DataFilter<double> df(&dr, 0.0, 10.0);
    ofstream os("RangeErrors.dat");

    if(os.is_open())
        while(true) {
            double value;
            try {
                while(df.getNextValue(value))
                    vec.push_back(value);
                printResults();
                os.close();
                return 0;
            }
            catch(range_error) {
                rangeErrorCounter++;
                os << value << endl;
            }
        }
    else
        cout << "Couldn't open RangeErrors.dat" << endl;
}

#endif
```

DataFilter.cpp

```
#include "DataFilter.h"

template <typename T>
bool DataFilter<T>::getNextValue(T &aValue) {
    if (fileReader.readNextValue(aValue)) {
        if (aValue > max || aValue < min)
            throw(range_error("Outside of range"));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

DataFilter.h

```
#ifndef DataFilter_H
#define DataFilter_H
#include "DataFileReader.h"

template <typename T> 
class DataFilter { 

    private: 
        DataFileReader<T> fileReader;
        T min, max;

    public: 
        DataFilter(DataFileReader<T> *aReader, T aMin, T aMax): fileReader(*aReader), min(aMin), max(aMax) {}; 
        /* pre: aReader points to an instance of DataFileReader<T> for which openFiles() has been succesfully called. */ 
        bool getNextValue(T &aValue); // throw (range_error); 
        /* pre: an earlier call to getNextValue() has not returned false. 
        post: true is returned if aValue holds a value read from aReader. If a value could not be read, false is returned. 
        If a value is read but is not within the interval specified by aMin and aMax parameters to the constructor, a range_error exception is thrown. */ 
};

#endif
```

Appreciate any help. After a few hours of searching around on SO and Google I'm still stumped...

Comment: You seem to misunderstand `dynamic_cast`. It means to general a pointer (or reference) to a base class or derived class.

Comment: You might be interested in [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

Comment: "I'm trying to cast from a string read from a file using dynamic_cast..." - *why* are you trying to do that? `dynamic_cast` has a well-defined and a very specific functionality. It doesn't do anything that would even remotely match what you are asking from it. There's absolutely no meaningful way `dynamic_cast` can be applied to a `string` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `dynamic_cast` to cast a `string` variable to a data type that is not derived from `string`.  Doing so is a compile-time error, you cannot catch it at run-time.

If you want to parse a `string` value into a different type, use `istringstream`, eg:

```
if (!(dataFileStream >> readValue)) // did I/O fail?
    return false;
istringstream iss(readValue);
if (!(iss >> aValue)) // did parsing fail?
    return false;
return iss.eof(); // was the entire value consumed?
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. If the conversion to double in this case can't be done (say, the read string contains both numbers and letters), does istringstream show this somehow (exceptions?)? As I need to catch any none-convertable entries to use these in a different way.

Comment: Let's say `readValue` is `"123abc"`. Using `istringstream`, reading a double would return `123`. You can use `eof()` to account for that.

Comment: @Matt McNabb: No, it wouldn't. Firstly, `dynamic_cast` can only cast to pointer and reference types. And in cast to pointer types the argument has to be a pointer too. Secondly, if the target class was derived from `std::string`, then such `dynamic_cast` would be a *downcast*. Downcast required polymorphic type as a source. But `std::string` is not polymorphic.

Comment: @Matt McNabb: The only legal way to apply `dynamic_cast` to a non-polymorphic object of type `U` is to cast to reference to some *base* class of `U` or to `U &`. Since `std::string` has no base classes, the only remaining option is the redundant `dynamic_cast<string &>(...)`.